# Visual Studio dumpbin utility

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

Can somebody help with visual studio dumpbin ? I need to calculate total size of *.lib. I use key \SUMMARY . I received such print like ".debug$s" ".idata$2", ".idata$3" ...

What that fields mean ? 
How I can calculate total size? Is this size on bytes ?

UPDATE :  [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch7pq.png) THANK'S everybody for answers )

Comment: Why are you using dumpbin instead of Explorer? Just look at the size of the LIB file. Not that this is particularly meaningful. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: I need to calculate size of lib file and generate sample xml file. It is necessary to getting same result of build of project. So do you know what this field mean ? THANKS

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. What does an XML file have to do with a LIB file? What would the XML file look like?

Comment: I have wrote about *.xml, cause you ask me what I really trying to solve. Xml file does not connect with my problem. it's ok. 

My problem conected with calculating total size due to dumpbin.exe utility  visual studio 10. I need to revise such result  in Windows like in Linux generate by "size -t " command. In Linux "size -t" generate  (TOTAL). Total size of file. Win command line don't have such.  This is my problem. 
And I would like to know i can calculate size using only result of dumbin.exe utility. Thank you.